# Why can't I import an string array as there are a error in log that says "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence"

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I am trying to set a button that display the next line of the dialog `onClick` using an array(concept like a text based adventure game), but as I import the **.xml**, which is just a simple  that stored all the dialog.

```
package com.example.project;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn_message;
String[] messages;
    int index = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Importing values
        messages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
        btn_message=findViewById(R.id.btn_message);

        //set Value to varibles

        btn_message.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        index++;
        btn_message.setText(messages [index]);
    }
}
```

In case needed
**Logcat:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
        at com.example.project.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**string.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="messages">
        <item>test1</item>
        <item>test2</item>
        <item>test3</item>
        <item>test4</item>
        <item>test5</item>
        <item>test6</item>
        <item>test7</item>
        <item>test8</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Layout:**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_message"
        android:layout_width="713dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Expected the button clicked and the text on button change, but the app crashed due to:

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Answer (score 1):

The `Button#setText()` method receives a String which is an implementation of CharSequence, and when you do `messages[index]` you are getting an ArrayList containing each cell of the line in an element, so an array of arrays.

You should collect them in one string. One way of doing it, if the list is `List<String>`, is:

```
String stringMessage = String.join(", ", messages[index]);
```

Then you should be able to make the `setText()` cal without exceptions:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        index++;
        String stringMessage = String.join(", ", messages[index]);
        btn_message.setText(stringMessage);
    }
```

Like this you will join them with a coma and a space `,`, if you want to join them somehow else, just specify another joining string in the first parameter of `#join()`

If the ArrayList is not of String, you can use lambdas to perform the same operation:

```
String messageString = messages[index].stream().map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be helpful

```
index++; btn_message.setText(messages [index].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make it as following the condition if onClick  for avoiding out of range exception

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn_message;
String[] messages;
int index = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    messages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
    btn_message=findViewById(R.id.btn_message);

    //set Value to varibles

    btn_message.setText(messages[index++]);
    btn_message.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(index < messages.length) {
        btn_message.setText(messages[index]);
        index++;
    }else{
        index = 0;
        btn_message.setText(messages[index++]);
    }
}
```

}